# Error while building solution Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow - CSC error CS7065: Error building Win32 resources

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csc

Got this error while building solution on CI server using VS2019 - 16.7.4

Any idea from where it could come from ? It doesn't happen all the time and only one solution. Can workaround by cleaning completely build working folder

```
CSC error CS7065: Error building Win32 resources : Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
```

Comment: Please change every resource files's `Build Action` to `Resource`. Right-click on every resource file on the solution explorer-->`Properties`. Besides, check every resource file's format is right.

Comment: Also, enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed`. and then build your project to get the detailed error log. Also, you can share that with us. Any detailed description for this issue is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, please enter VS IDE, **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**Build and Run**--> set **MSBuild project build output verbosity** to `Detailed` to get the detailed build log to locate the specific error.

If you use msbuild command line, you can add `-v:detailed` to get the detailed build log.

**Then**, try the following steps:

**1)** check every resource files, right-click on every that file-->Properties-->change its **Build Action** to `Resource` or Content`.

[image]

**2)** try to use **Configuration** `Any CPU` to build your project.

**3)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder and then rebuild your project again.

**Besides**, if the issue still persists, please share more detailed build log and description about the issue so that it will help us troubleshoot the issue quickly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Issue is a bit "random".
Good point i added verbose for next time it i can reproduce it in order to grasp more detailed logs.
1) not sure it applies to all item since i have some a solution with around 90 projects and some embedded ressources , database project.
2) already Any CPU
3) new msbuild instance is spinup there for each build step on team city
This is what i did for "workaround" the issue, i start build by deleting working folder and indeed after this is working but i don't undertand still root cause since on other solutions never got that issue.

Comment: Glad to know that you have solved the issue. deleting working folder every time to prevent the previous coupling error build. Since step 3 helps you handle the issue, I suggest you could `accept the answer` so that it will help other community members handle the similar issues. If you have a better workaround, you could add an answer here:)

Comment: i would like still to understand root cause but no luck. Also i removed from build v:detailed parameter since was creating huge build logs, impossible to use anymore teamcity build logs output which was a no-no

Comment: Or you could try to build your project in vs ide to check what is wrong. Using error list of VS IDE might be a good choice. Or you could use `-v:normal` to reduce the log.

Comment: i never get the issue locally with VS, only on build server "randomly"

Comment: It is quite strange. And remove `bin` and `obj` folder and then restart build task on the team city again.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, there was a weird combination of characters in the AssemblyInfo.cs
When I removed all these rubbish and changed that to

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © HP Inc. 2021")]
```

It built normal

[image]